# PHP, extract facebook user's image and save it into db

Tags: php

My website use facebook login api to make people to log in easily.

I could get user's facebook profile image if I know their facebook ID number.

```
$fb_id = $this->input->post('fb_id');
$fb_image_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large';
```

so if I have right id number and post the url on website, it redirects to jpg address.

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/274661_1171545457_647564606.jpg
```

Therefore, I can't use the first address to save the image file into db.

I need to do something to get real image address before I use $fb_image_url.

is there a way to get the final address by using PHP?

Comment: Why can't you use first url to save in your database? `<img class="profilePicImg" width="90" src="<?php echo $fb_profile_pic; ?>" />`

Comment: @zaw because loading image from facebook causes some problem on mobile application. so I'd rather save it into my db.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_id/picture?type=large.');` *should* be able to grab the img contents.  Did you try that?